# Merge 2 arrays using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

I have two simple array and I would like to merge using join linq:

```
int[] num1 = new int[] { 1, 55, 89, 43, 67, -3 };
int[] num2 = new int[] { 11, 35, 79, 23, 7, -10 };

var result = from n1 in num1
             from n2 in num2
             select result;
```

Comment: Do you need to merge them and iterate over the result, or should they be merged into another array?

Comment: The alleged duplicate asks a different question: it talks about merging an array of arrays into a single list (i.e. `SelectMany`), while this question asks to merge two arrays (i.e. `Concat`). Nominating the question for re-opening.

Answer (score 40):

You can do it using [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) and [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx), like this:

```
var res = num1.Concat(num2).ToArray();
```

This will put all elements of `num2` after elements of `num1`, producing `res` that looks like

```
int[] { 1, 55, 89, 43, 67, -3, 11, 35, 79, 23, 7, -10 };
```

**EDIT :** (in response to a comment: "how can I also sort either allNumbers and res?")

Once your two arrays are merged, you can use `OrderBy` to sort the result, like this:

```
var res = num1.Concat(num2).OrderBy(v=>v).ToArray();
```

Comment: there is no function as Concatenate

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but how can I also sort either allNumbers and res?

Comment: I am sorry.. V=> v stands for?

Comment: @user2252054 That's a *lambda function* (a fancy name for a function with no name) that returns its argument. `OrderBy` lets you sort by anything that can be derived from the item being sorted. When items are integers, there's little to derive, although I suppose you could write `v=>Math.Abs(v)` to sort by the absolute value, or something similar to it. When you sort objects with attributes, however, you could select an attribute, like this: `OrderBy(person => person.LastName)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = num1.Concat(num2);
```

Doesn't allocate any memory. Is this sufficient for your needs?

Answer (score 3):

```
var allNumbers = num1.Concat(num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Concat`

```
  var res= num1.Concat(num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below... it will help you..

```
int[] num1 = new int[] { 1, 55, 89, 43, 67, -3 };
int[] num2 = new int[] { 11, 35, 79, 23, 7, -10 };
var result = num1.Union(num2).ToArray();
```

Comment: What is the difference between concat and Union? Is one distinct and the other one not?

Comment: @Tobias: Yes, Union is distinct. Given two sequences {1, 2, 3} & {2, 3, 4} Union gives {1, 2, 3, 4}, concat gives {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4}