# Loading data from file depending on data selected from calendar view?

Tags: c#

Currently I have a program that will load in a file containing data and then output all of that data into a table in appropriate columns. What I was wondering is if it was possible to have a user select a specific date on a calendar view and then it will only select the data that contains that data within it. Here is the code that I use for the loading the data into the table:

```
                private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {



            {


                //List<string> colHeaders = new List<string>();

                var lines = File.ReadAllLines("F:\\data.hrm").SkipWhile(f => !f.StartsWith("[HRData]")).Skip(1);
                foreach (var line in lines)
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(line.Split(
                        new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
            }

            int total = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Sum(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells[0].Value));




        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int speed = 0;
        int power = 0;
        int hrate = 0;
        int altitude = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            speed += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            power += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
            hrate += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            altitude += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);


            int count_row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            double avgspeed = speed / count_row;
                            double avgpower = power / count_row;

                            double avghrate = hrate / count_row;
            double avgaltitude = altitude / count_row;


                            txt.Text = "Your average speed was: " + avgspeed.ToString() + "\r" + "your average power was : " + avgpower.ToString() + "\r" + "Your average heart rate was : " + avghrate.ToString() + "\r" + "Your average altitude was : " + avgaltitude.ToString() + "\r";

        }

        var Maxspeed = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Max(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["speed"].Value));


        txt.Text = txt.Text + "Your max speed was: " + Maxspeed + "\r";

        var Maxpower = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Max(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["watts"].Value));

        txt.Text = txt.Text + "Your max power was: " + Maxpower + "\r";


        var Maxhrate = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Max(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["HeartRate"].Value));

        txt.Text = txt.Text + "Your max heart rate was: " + Maxhrate + "\r";


        var MaxAltitude = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Max(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["altitude"].Value));

        txt.Text = txt.Text + "Your max altitude was: " + MaxAltitude + "\r";

        var minhrate = 777;
         minhrate = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Min(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["HeartRate"].Value));

        txt.Text = txt.Text + "Your min heart rate was: " + minhrate + "\r";



        }


    }
}
```

and here is a snippet of the data itself that is actually being read into the form:

```
[Params]
Version=106
Monitor=34
SMode=111111100
Date=20130205
StartTime=15:46:20.0
Length=01:06:18.9


//n header 
[HRData]
91  154 70  309 83  6451
91  154 70  309 83  6451
92  160 75  309 87  5687
94  173 80  309 87  5687
```

Comment: We're going to need more context about your data.  Where is the date/time field that you want to use as a filter?  Your code seems to be incomplete.

Comment: Oh sorry I just cut out the pieces of code that actually load data into the field I will update with my full code as well as a snippet of data.

Comment: OK, still not quite up on context.  It would seem that you're going to need a pair of classes - one for Params, and an array of classes within that of HRData.

Then use LINQ to get just the ones with the date you're after.

Making a lot of guesses about your context, here.

Comment: @wesleyLong http://pastebin.com/pjRpjggi this is the full data sorry I'm not clear on what you mean by context

Comment: OK,I'm only seeing one Date value in there, at all.  How are you getting multiple dates that you have to filter?  Sorry if I'm just being dense.

Comment: Oh sorry, this is a data file for only one day that I'm using for testing. I was thinking that if I could get the calendar view to load in the data for this date when selected it would apply for the other dates with other files as well.

Comment: So that entire sequence repeats?

Comment: The data is all in that exact format but with different values yes.

Comment: If it wasn't clear I would like to have a calendar view then when the user selects a date from that calendarview then it will load only the data from that data into the datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm not going to go over deserializing the data, but you need two classes:

1) Params (or whatever)  That contains properties for these

- Version
- Monitor
- SMode
- Date
- StartTime
- Length
- Readings - will be Reading[]

2) Reading
 - Speed
 - Power
 - HeartRate
 - Altitude

Then you need to parse your file, and generate an array of Params classes, and while "inside" each Params, generate an array of each Reading and nest it.

I am not going to write this for you, but once you have that array, you should be able to filter them with LINQ.

Functions you'll need along the way:

DateTime.Parse, maybe DateTime.ParseExact
T[].Where
T[].Concat - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16012416/820068

That should get you started.

Comment: This is all I needed really I wasn't sure where to start thanks.